# WindowManager gives 'System services not available to Activities before onCreate()' Exception when trying to add ListView with it

Tags: android

I am trying to set `ListView` on `WindowManager` like this:

`public class Window extends Service {

```
WindowManager mwindow;
ViewGroup vg;
int ListId=+1;
ListView listView;
MainActivity.Custom main;







@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();


    main=new MainActivity().new Custom();
    listView=new ListView(this);




    LinearLayout linearLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearp=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(linearp);


    LinearLayout.LayoutParams listp=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    listView.setId(ListId);
    listView.setAdapter(main);
    main.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    linearLayout.addView(listView,listp);





    mwindow=(WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams myParams=new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    myParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    myParams.x=0;
    myParams.y=100;


    mwindow.addView(linearLayout,myParams);
```

}`

The resource or adapter for my `Listview` is getting from a `innerClass` named Custom in `MainActivity` like this:

` class Custom extends ArrayAdapter

```
{
    Custom(){

        super(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,iconList);
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View row=convertView;

        if(row==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.icon,null);

            ImageView image=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageViewicons);
            image.setImageDrawable(iconList.get(position));
        }
        return row;
    }
}`
```

But when I try to run the code it gives me
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.example.adarsh.test.Window: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()`

Whats the problem Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Move your code to onResume and let android have the onCreate for creating required services. As you exception message says, you are trying to use System service before its made available on your app.

Comment: mwindow=(WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE); //I believe your error is on this line
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams myParams=new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    myParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    myParams.x=0;
    myParams.y=100;


    mwindow.addView(linearLayout,myParams);

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by the following lines:

`main=new MainActivity().new Custom();` (in your Service)

and

`super(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,iconList);` (in your adapter)

Manually instantiating an Activity class doesn't make it go through the lifecycle events - and later on the adapter is using a reference to it as a context - probably crashing in

`LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();` if not earlier.

You need to decouple the adapter from the activity if you need to use it in the service.

Comment: please tell me how can I do that

Comment: You could take out adapter from your activity and move it into a separate file of its own. If you can't do that, pass other context reference to the adapter (instead of using Activity.this) (add the context to the constructor, so that you can specify it from anywhere). When used from Activity - pass the activity as parameter; and when used from Service, pass the service (Service is a Context):

Comment: `Custom(Context context){
    super(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,iconList);
}`

In service:
`main = new MainActivity().new Custom(this);`

Comment: OK separate file means making a new java class as we do by clicking on new option in android studio to make a new java class file